# Edited version not showing to question viewers

Tags: bug, status-norepro, edits, revisions-list

Looking at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/106997/why-doesnt-my-dvd-player-work-under-windows-7) on SU there was an edit by Ivo which isn't showing as rolled-back, yet I still see the original question text on the main question page rather than the edited one. I've seen this before recently, though didn't take note of the URL (sorry for being a bad user and not giving full details in a bug report!).

The first version in the edit history shows as:

```
since upgrading to W7, I cant use the DVD player.
Is there a fix for that here or a new DVD download?
```

with Ivo's edited version being:

```
Why doesn't my DVD player work under Windows 7?
```

with an additional tag (hardware-problem). I see the new tag when looking at the main question page, but still see the original question text. I've tried in a different browser (one I don't normally touch SO/SF/SU with) to make sure it isn't a local caching issue here.

Comment: Looks the same across three views. Questions, Home, Question itself.

Answer (score 2):

The homepage is cached for about 60 seconds. This is normal.

(looks fine to me now)

Comment: I'm still seeing the wrong text (unless I'm misreading the edit history display of course!). I've added a little extra detail to the report.